# UIView action - UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an action hooked up to a UIView. the action was working fine until I turned the alpha of the UIView down to 0. Does anyone know why this might happen or a workaround?

the action is for a UIView that when swiped with a UISwipeGestureRecognizer performs an action.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK views that have an alpha value below a certain threshold (0.1 or so) don't receive touch events.

Comment: I'm not so sure of this - (I'm not arguing, but) if you're using a UIButton, you can set the type to custom and the background to `UIClearColor` and it will still respond.  It's completely invisible, but it responds to touches.

Comment: ok, I was considering a UIButton instead. thanks for the info.